# Entity Framework 6 and MySql error in double looping select and datareader

Tags: mysql, entity-framework, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, entity-framework-6

I am following a video lesson to learn about EF 6 + MySql, so far it was easy, but now I have a simple problem with a code and I've spent 8h on it but have no solutions yet. The error is on the second Foreach in the "cli.contatos":

```
        var db = new apagartesteentityEntities(); // create model

        // runs the read on "clientes" table
        foreach (var cli in db.clientes) 
        {
            Console.WriteLine(cli.NomeClientes);

            // runs a read in "contatos" table looking for relations
            foreach (var cont in cli.contatos)                 {// <--error 
                Console.WriteLine(cont.TipoContato);
                Console.WriteLine(cont.ValorContato);
            }

        }
        Console.Read();
```

So here is the code, it is EXACTLY the same on the video lession, but the "teacher" uses SqlServer and I use MySql. The "exception" says that there's already a DataReader open that must to be closed but it do not help me.

-I've already update the MySql connector and MySql Visual studio
-already overwrited the dll
-already start the project updating EntityFramework, MySql.Data, MySql.Entity from nuget BEFORE create the model.

I am starting now with EF 6 so any help woulb be apreciate. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL Server supports a feature called Multiple Active Result Sets (MARS), this is not supported by MySQL, so the error you are seeing is expected. You'll need to open a second connection and run a second query in the inner loop.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you! I would never wonder something like that! Look, I did what you say and changed the code so now I GUESS it is working(until now it is ok), if you have some hint I could take it, Im not a programmer yet, I dont even speak english, but really thank you! I will "answer" intead comment so I can show the code for others who may need it.

```
        var db = new apagartesteentityEntities();
        contatos con = new contatos();

        foreach (var cli in db.clientes)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Nome do cliente: "+ cli.NomeClientes);
```

*// the 2th model/connection "inside the using" so it "dies" in the loop (i guess)*

```
            using(var db2 = new apagartesteentityEntities())               
            { 
            // MySql Nao suporta MARS (multiple actives result set)
            foreach (var cont in db2.contatos) 
            {
                if (cont.IdClientes == cli.IdClientes) {  // reads IF the FK matches the PK
                Console.WriteLine("Tipo contato: "+cont.TipoContato);
                Console.WriteLine("Valor do contato: "+cont.ValorContato);
                }
            }
            }
        Console.WriteLine("--------------------");
        }
        Console.Read();
```

Comment: I'm not very familiar with EF coding so I'm not certain of the right way to do that but I think you should rather put a Where in the inner loop otherwise you are getting all the contatos from the database every time and then looping through them to match to the cliente. The code is _probably_ something like this     
    `foreach (var cont in db2.contatos.Where(co => co.IdClientes == cli.IdClientes))
    {
        ...
    }`